# Nuclearity of $C(\partial_F \mathbb{G})$

Tags: c-star-algebras, quantum-groups, injective-modules, nuclear-spaces

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a discrete quantum group, and consider the [non-commutative Furstenberg boundary](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.09657) $\partial_F\mathbb{G}$ with function algebra $C(\partial_F \mathbb{G}) = I_{\mathbb{G}}(\mathbb{C})$. Here, $I_\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{C})$ is injective so has a $C^*$-algebra structure coming from the Choi-Effros product.

Is something known about nuclearity of this $C^*$-algebra? Of course, if $\mathbb{G}$ is a classical discrete group, then $C(\partial_F\mathbb{G})$ is commutative, so nuclear. Are there non-trivial examples known of genuine discrete quantum groups where this $C^*$-algebra is nuclear or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a bound on the size of matrix blocks in $\ell_\infty(G)$, then this algebra is nuclear by a result of S. Wassermann [1], which would imply the nuclearity of $I_G(\mathbb{C})$. Without such a bound, his result says that $\ell_\infty(G)$ is not nuclear, and I don't see any reason why $I_G(\mathbb{C})$ should be nuclear then (unless $G$ is amenable).

1. *Wassermann, Simon*, [**On tensor products of certain group (C^*)-algebras**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(76)90050-1), J. Funct. Anal. 23, 239-254 (1976). [ZBL0358.46040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0358.46040).

Comment: This is nice, thanks! It might be interesting to note that if there is a bound on the size of the matrix blocks, we are in the Kac-case, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04863.pdf

Comment: It might be worth noting that if $\ell_\infty(G)$ is subhomogeneous then it is not just nuclear, it is Type I, in which case every Cstar-subalgebra is itself Type I and hence nuclear.

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't think $C(\partial_F G)$ is a subalgebra of $\ell_\infty(G)$ though. The $C^*$-algebra structure comes from the Choi-Effros product.

Comment: @J.DeRo Oops, you are quite right. I suspect that the range of a conditional expectation on a Type I Cstar algebra, equipped with the Choi-Effros product, might still be Type I, but I admit that I do not have a proof or reference for such a claim.

Comment: @YemonChoi I'm not sure about Type I but the range equipped with the CE product is at least nuclear since it satisfies the CPAP